# How to bypass CSP and load remote images from a Safari Extension

Tags: javascript, safari, content-security-policy, chrome-extension-manifest-v3, safari-extension

We have a extension on all the major browsers, everything works fine on Chrome, Firefox, Opera and Edge but on Safari we are unable to load remote images on some pages where the CSP is strict, for example in twitter.com

It seems the extension bypass this for all the browsers except in safari, we understand that there is the option of serving the images locally from the extension but this is not an option for us due the big amount of files we might need to load.

Is there anything that we can do to avoid this problem? We tried almost everything on "web_accessible_resources" but it seems to have no effect at all.

We are also noticing that this directives also cause issues with some post requests where it just returns a cached answer.

Comment: Could be a bug in Safari. Try downloading the images using `fetch` in the background script and convert them into data: URI. The web_accessible_resources approach should also work so it's either another bug in Safari (e.g. they block external images in extension pages) or you didn't use it correctly.

Comment: This is what I tried with the accessible resources:  

"web_accessible_resources": [{
    {
      "resources": [
        " *.png"
      ],
      "matches": [ "http://*/*","https://*/*" ]
    }
  ],

also replacing the matches for "<all_urls>" and the concrete url of our cdn. but it seem to do no difference... 


This approach of converting them into data: URI seems promising, could you refer an example on how to do this? Thank you!

Comment: 1) The purpose of web_accessible_resources is to show resources from the extension directory, not from other servers. 2) There should be lots of examples. In short you would use `createImageBitmap` and `OffscreenCanvas` (in your service worker) or `Image` and `Canvas` (in an [offscreen](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/offscreen/) document).